# LocalDB 2016 v13 on 32 bits computer

Tags: visual-studio, localdb, mdf

Is there a 32 bits installer for LocalDB 2016? Because I can't find it.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52679

My problem is that I have an application with a MDF that Visual Studio keeps telling to update from v12 (2014) to v13 (2016) but I can't because I can't see a 32 bits version of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 32 bits version of any edition of SQL Server 2016

Comment: Do you know how can I create and manage with Visual Studio v12 (not v13) MDF files? My problem is that it forces me to use always v13 and I don't want it because it's limited to 64 bits.